# CSS - How to reverse the Animation on removal

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a page in my website where I display to panels, side by side. I'm displaying these 2 panels in 2 views: Horizontal and Vertical. I have a button that switches between these 2 views. I'm trying to add some CSS animation on the transition between the two views. However my animation work only in one direction (from Vertical to Horizontal), the reverse animation appear in the wrong order.

```js
var isVertical = false;
var boxes = $(".box");

function toggleViews() 
{ 
  isVertical = !isVertical;
  if (isVertical)
  {
    boxes.addClass("vertical-box");
  }
  else
  {
    boxes.removeClass("vertical-box");
  }
}
```

```css
.container 
{
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box 
{
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s, 2s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;

  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.vertical-box 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
.a { background-color: darkred; }
.b { background-color: darkorchid; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="toggleViews()">toggle</button>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a box">A</div><div class="b box">B</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var isVertical = false;
var boxes = $(".box");

function toggleViews() 
{ 
  isVertical = !isVertical;
  if (isVertical)
  {
    boxes.addClass("vertical-box");
  }
  else
  {
    boxes.removeClass("vertical-box");
  }
}
```

```css
.container 
{
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box 
{
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width; /* swapped */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;

  display: block; /* TRY THIS */
  float: left; /* AND THIS */
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.vertical-box 
{
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height; /* added */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
.a { background-color: darkred; }
.b { background-color: darkorchid; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="toggleViews()">toggle</button>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a box">A</div><div class="b box">B</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Explained**

Added `transition-property: width, height;` to `.vertical-box`

Desired behavior: expand width, shink height; expand height shrink width.

`.box` has `transition-property` first height then width
`.vertical-box` overwrites and flippes transition-property: first width, then height

You might think this is the wrong order, but as soon as you click the class is applied immideately, but the transition takes time. So you transition from `.box` to `.vertical-box` with the transition-property of `.vertical-box` and vise versa.

**EDIT** Answer using animation (little hacky, since i found no way to reset current keyframe)

```js
var isVertical = false;
var boxes = $(".box");

function toggleViews() 
{ 
  isVertical = !isVertical;
  if (isVertical)
  {
    boxes.removeClass("vertical-box-reverse");
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { // apply to forget animation state
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { // re-apply animation
        boxes.addClass("vertical-box");
      });
    });
  }
  else
  {
    boxes.removeClass("vertical-box");
      
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { // apply to forget animation state
    boxes.addClass("vertical-box-before-reverse"); // apply to set animation end-like state
     window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { // re-apply animation
      boxes.removeClass("vertical-box-before-reverse");
      boxes.addClass("vertical-box-reverse");
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.container 
{
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box 
{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.a.vertical-box { animation: boxAnimationA 1s normal forwards; }
.b.vertical-box { animation: boxAnimationB 1s normal forwards; }

.a.vertical-box-reverse { animation: boxAnimationA 1s ease-in reverse forwards; }
.b.vertical-box-reverse { animation: boxAnimationB 1s ease-in reverse forwards; }

.vertical-box-before-reverse { width: 100%; height: 50%; }


.a { background-color: darkred; }
.b { background-color: darkorchid; }

/* Keyframes */
@keyframes boxAnimationA {
  0% { width: 50%; }
  50% { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
  100% { width: 100%; height: 50%; }
}

@keyframes boxAnimationB {
  0% { width: 50%; }
  50% { width: 0%; height: 100%; }
  51% { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
  100% { width: 100%; height: 50%; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="toggleViews()">toggle</button>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a box">A</div><div class="b box">B</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add explain of what you did will be nice!

Comment: @לבנימלכה sure will do, hold on :)

Comment: @Pilan, is it possible to delay the `display` property? So it will change only after the animation had ended?

Comment: @GilEpshtain im not sure what you mean - because the `display` property does not change during animation.

Comment: @GilEpshtain i guess you want the purple part to not disappear immediately, but shink first?

Comment: @Pilan, I know that display property can't be animated (that's my problem). is it possible to change the display (from inline-block to block) after 2s (animation duration). Meaning that once the animation started the display will be inline-block, and after 2s (once the animation ended) the display will change to black

Comment: @GilEpshtain in this case its no longer a transition. You may want to have a look at [animations](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) for this. BUT before you take off, better tell me what the desired behavior is, maybe there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: @GilEpshtain I edited the solution a bit, maybe this is what you actually wanted?

Comment: @Pilan, If you run your solution (code-snippet) you can see that box-B displaying @animation when appearing from below, but immediately appearing (without animation) from the right-side. This happening because the `display` property need to change from `block` (at class .box) to `inline-block` (at class .vertical-box).

Comment: @GilEpshtain ok, again. What is the desired behavior? I guess no white space at any given time of transition? The problem here is during transition both elements exceed 100% width, so they wrap. display block or inline wont help there.

Comment: @GilEpshtain added an animation answer having the(i think) desired behavior